# Using an MKTileOverlay with an MKPolyLine

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios7, mkpolyline

I have a working MKTileOverlay and MKPolyline on my MKMapView but need to update the polyline every second or so. I do this currently by removing the old line and adding a new one with the next point added. At the moment this does work but causes the tiles of the MKTileOverlay to be reloaded. Is it possible to have a mutable polyline or replace it without reloading all of the tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to `[UIView drawRect:]`, the new `MKTileOverlayRenderer` descends from `MKOverlayRenderer` and has `rect`-based screen updates. So you could figure out the start point of your mutable segment addition, the end point, and use those as opposite corners on an `MKMapRect` which should be refreshed. That is, you'd just refresh the overlay tile(s) involved with the new segment, not the whole path.

Comment: To be more complete you should get the bounding rect of the modified line segment, rather than just the end points. For example if the line went from San Diego to Seattle via Denver you'd want to refresh all the tiles away from the coast too.